# using case when in sum function is returning wrong results for an aggregated table that is joined to itself in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, row-number, amazon-athena

I have a table of transactions from customers who buy credits for our products. Let's just say for this example it's for pizza products. When a customer buys credits a new row is added to the table with their customer_id, amount uploaded, date_time, note describing whether credits were bought or another type of transaction, their previous balance, voucher balance, and condition explaining whether the process was confirmed or not.

I want to make a new table by getting some stats for each user. So I want a table that consists only of one row for each user. Along with the stats I want to have their last balance included. In order to do this I have to get the last row for each user and join it back to itself or at least that was my impression from the answers I saw online. this is my attempt along with some sample data.

```
CREATE TABLE pizza_transactions
    (customer_id int, 
     amount int, 
     date_time date,
     note varchar,
     previous_balance int,
     previous_voucher_balance int,
    condition1 varchar)
;
    
INSERT INTO pizza_transactions
    (customer_id, amount, date_time, note,previous_balance, previous_voucher_balance, condition1)
VALUES
    (1, 10, '2022-01-01','Pizza credits bought',100,50,'confirmed'),
    (1, -45, '2022-02-02','something else',110,50, 'processing'),
    (2, 70, '2022-05-1','Pizza credits bought',20,5,'confirmed'),
    (3, 20, '2022-09-01','Pizza credits bought',10,15,'confirmed'),
    (3, 10, '2022-09-02','Pizza credits bought',30,15,'confirmed'),
    (3, -15, '2022-09-03','something else',40,15,'processing')
```

```
select u.customer_id,
sum(case when note like '%Pizza credits bought%' and condition1 = 'confirmed' then amount else 0 end) as total_bought,
avg(case when note like '%Pizza credits bought%' and condition1 = 'confirmed' then amount end) as avg_bought,
min(case when note like '%Pizza credits bought%' then date_time end) as first_purchased_date,
max(case when note like '%Pizza credits bought%' then date_time end) as last_purchased_date,
max(case when hu.rn1 = 1 then hu.previous_balance end) as last_balance,
max(case when hu.rn1 = 1 then hu.previous_voucher_balance end) as last_voucher_balance
from pizza_transactions as u
inner join (
        select  row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by date_time desc) as rn1,
        previous_balance,
        previous_voucher_balance,
        customer_id
        from pizza_transactions
        ) as hu
        on u.customer_id = hu.customer_id
group by u.customer_id;
```

This query however returns a table with some right information except for the newly created column called total_bought. After playing around with the query I realized the join was causing duplicate rows and that is why the sum of the amount was wrong. I then tried to get rid of the duplicate rows by changing my SQL query to look like this

```
select u.customer_id,
sum(case when u.note like '%Pizza credits bought%' and u.condition1 = 'confirmed' then amount else 0 end) as total_bought,
avg(case when u.note like '%Pizza credits bought%' and u.condition1 = 'confirmed' then amount end) as avg_bought,
min(case when u.note like '%Pizza credits bought%' then u.date_time end) as first_purchased_date,
max(case when u.note like '%Pizza credits bought%' then u.date_time end) as last_purchased_date,
max(hu.previous_balance) as last_balance,
max(hu.previous_voucher_balance) as last_voucher_balance
from pizza_transactions as u
left join (select *
           from (
             select  row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by date_time desc) as rn1,
             previous_balance,
             previous_voucher_balance,
             customer_id
        from pizza_transactions )t
        where t.rn1 = 1
        ) as hu
        on u.customer_id = hu.customer_id;
group by u.customer_id
```

But this returned **ERROR: column "u.customer_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function Position: 8**. I did however get rid of the duplicate rows.

So my question is how can I aggregate a table and group by users and then add their last balances to this table? I can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: Remove that `;` before `group by u.customer_id` in the last query and it will work: https://dbfiddle.uk/cTcTXJ93

Comment: Oh man such a little thing, and yet I did not notice it. Thank you. If you want to put the correct query as an answer. I will select it as the right answer.